# nonexistent pipe bat file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to create a .bat file for formatting disks. Every time I run the script it doesn't work and says it's trying to write to a nonexistent pipe. I haven't found any obvious reason why it wouldn't work. I have also found no answer anywhere else.
this is the code

```
:loop
echo list disk|diskpart|find "Online"
set "disk=."
set /p "disk=Pick disk number above to destroy/reformat: "
echo.
echo list disk|diskpart|find "Disk %disk%"
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo Invalid drive selection!
 pause
 goto :loop
) else (
 echo select Disk %disk%
 echo clean
 echo create partition primary
 echo select partition=1
 echo active
 echo format fs=fat32
 echo assign
 echo exit
)| REM diskpart
pause
```

Comment: I would recommend that you never try to perform destructive tasks with a batch file. I will not, and I've been writing batch files for well over 30 years. I would also strongly advise you not to use `set /p` for end user input without having implemented some very robust input validation, prior to using that input. At the `set /p` prompt, an end user can type nothing, _(which in this case would pass through as `.`)_, or anything at all, including poison characters, and malicious code, _(which could close your script, or cause untold damage)_.

Comment: There's no way known I'd go anywhere near testing a script that's using `diskpart`. I'd suggest your first step is to locate exactly where the non-existent pipe is being referenced (Hmm... look carefully for something that isn't there, begorrah...) So - does it reach the `if`? If so, try replacing `rem diskpart` with something innocuous like `|sort`or `|more`. I'm not too happy about the `pause` commands in the `else` block...

Comment: Looking at your code, there is nothing wrong with the pipes on lines `2` and `6`, so I'd assume your issue is with the one on the last line.

Comment: @Magoo I changed out the rem diskpart to sort and it does as expected and sorts with no problems. As soon as I put the diskpart back the problem reoccurs. Oh and yes it does reach the if.

Comment: @JesseMäenpää, I posted an answer, then noticed that you have edited your code to make it invalid. Please now test your as currently posted code, and report back whether your issue has gone. I suspect it has. _BTW, you did not need to remove them both!_

Comment: I would also suggest that you replace `else` with a line return.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that your issue was with the `pause` command you were trying to pipe to `diskpart` after you had `exit`ed it.

You have for some reason, now removed both your `pause` commands, so your issue should now have gone.

You should be able to recreate the issue, with this non destructive example:

```batch-file
@(  echo exit
    pause)|diskpart
@timeout -1
```

The simplest fix is to redirect the error message to the NUl device:

```batch-file
@(  echo exit
    pause 2>nul)|diskpart
@timeout -1
```

Comment: Issue is still happening. Removing the pauses did nothing.

Comment: First point, the first example above, does reproduce your error, and the second one does not. I cannot see how there is any doubt as to the cause. Additionally, I, and others, have absolutely no intention of running your supplied code, with or without the `pause` commands, @JesseMäenpää. So the best way to get assistance is to remove any `echo off` from your code, and paste into your question, *(formatted as code)*, the entire output from your script, so that we can see every command used and the output from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i'm an idiot.

I just removed the `rem` and now it works.

so the code is now:

```
:loop
echo list disk|diskpart|find "Online"
set "disk=."
set /p "disk=Pick disk number above to destroy/reformat: "
echo.
echo list disk|diskpart|find "Disk %disk%"
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Invalid drive selection!
pause
goto :loop
) else (
 echo select Disk %disk%
 echo clean
 echo create partition primary
 echo select partition=1
 echo active
 echo format fs=fat32
 echo assign
 echo exit
)|diskpart
pause
```

Comment: Are you seriously  telling us that you hadn't just inserted the `REM` as a courtesy to prevent others from destroying their data? The only reason for that to have been there was if you just copied the code from elsewhere, and the original author knew that it added a degree of security. Anyhow, try putting in the `pause` you had when you originally posted your question, like it was when I started typing my answer, and you'll get the same error message, just as my answer shows. I'm glad you've got it sorted, but I honestly cannot believe that you really were using that `REM` in your actual code!